# Android Retrofir2 Multipart remote API call set content type to 'application/json'

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, multipartform-data, multipart

I have the following remote REST api call in my Android Retrofit2 app.

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("user/testupload")
    suspend fun uploadUImage(
        @Part  person: PersonFull,
        @Part image: MultipartBody.Part
    ) : BaseResponseModel
```

I create the two parts like so below and then call the api in my code.

```
                val requestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())

                var filename = imageUrlPath + "_" + id.toString() + "_" + imageId

                val part2 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("person", Gson().toJson(personFull))
                val part1 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("productImage", filename, requestBody)
```

When the code hits the end point I get the following error:

```
Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported
```

How can I change the content type for part1 to 'application/json'?

Comment: We can specify header for particular request too.

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")

Comment: Thanks.  I tried but I am not getting the syntax for adding headers to a part.  Can you please help with an example?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can add Header on the method as well as you  can add httpClient to the retrofit.
The syntax to add the header.

```
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
 @POST("user/testupload")
 suspend fun uploadUImage(
    @Part  person: PersonFull,
    @Part image: MultipartBody.Part
 ) : BaseResponseModel
```

Adding header in each of the request is troublesome if you have many api methods to call so instead you add http client to the retrofit instance.
First creating a http client (copying from my old project as it was in java so the below code is in java )

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    httpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder();
            requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
        }
    });
```

And then add the this instance to the retrofit.

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new 
 Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).client(httpClient).build();
```

Comment: I don't understand how the above will ensure that the content type for part1 is "application/json" while for part2 it is "application/octet-stream".  thanks

Comment: do you mean you want to add header on each part ?

Comment: Part1 is a object and at the endpoint it will be in Json format and its content-type is "application/json".  Part2 is an image file and so its content-type is  "application/octet-stream".   How will I implement this?  Sorry if my original question was not clear.